# Stuck at Docker tutorial at step 6: Deploy your app

Tags: docker

I was following the Docker tutorial from step 1 - step 5, everything was fine by then.

But in [step 6](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part6/), I couldn't find any button or command from Docker for Mac or Docker Cloud. You can see the screenshot below.

And when I login to Docker Cloud, it automatically redirect me to https://cloud.docker.com/swarm/xdrealmadrid/repository/list , no place to me to find the command to deploy.

I don't know how to deploy the app to AWS at this point. My Docker for mac version is 18.03.0.

[image: docker for mac]

[image: docker cloud navigation bar]

[image: docker cloud repository]

Comment: Can you share the tutorial link? Deploying to AWS for docker containers can be done in a couple of ways and none of them is something so simple to be described in a open question on stackoverflow. You might be better off buying a course

Comment: Yes, https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part6/ (official tutorial)

Comment: I dont see the word or step login mentioned on that page at all. Could you please list the commands you are executing and what you expect to happen from them?

Comment: IMHO the official Docker tutorial part 2 is super super useful and everyone should read it, and beyond that they assume you’ve bought into Swarm, which is pretty optional.  As @Bizmate says you have several options including just plain `docker run` on an EC2 instance; you might clarify if you’re specifically trying to use Swarm or just want your container running on an instance somewhere.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I just want to deploy the local app to AWS based on how tutorial part 6 shows. In the tutorial, first they create swarm in docker cloud. But in my docker cloud dashboard, there is no button or link for me to create swarm, I just get stuck at this moment.